# formating sum decimal place in view aggregator plus

Tags: views

I am using view aggregation plus and views calc. I have calculate duration by subtracting two dates and display it with 1 decimal point. it work fine.

then I use sum function of view aggregation plus on views calc column to have total duration, everything work fine, but the result is with 4 decimal point i.e. 5.2302 it should display it as 5.2 only.

any suggestion how to set the decimal points of result of sum in view aggregation plus? I believe the problem is somewhere in view aggregation plus output formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [php field](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) to your view. Then hide the actual calc field from display and formatt the rounding in your php field:

```
<?php echo round($data->field_data_field_rating_field_rating_value,1); ?>
```

Comment: I think aggregation plus should have an option to round the sum. having a new column with php field may be  the solution but then I don't need calc field , why i would just hide? remember calc field calculate the duration of each record the aggregation sum up all the duration at the bottom of the view.

Comment: i tried view php module it gives global:php where I use code to calculate duration and able to use round function. But the problem is that I can't find how to expose this field's filter to the user? working with date and duration in drupal causing me headache.